# Software package for Python to receive coordinates of Wacom tablet?

Tags: osx, python

I need a python software package that collects the x & y coordinates of the pen movements on my Wacom tablet. Is there anything out there that gets the job done? I'm using Mac OS X Mojave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Wacom tablet is treated as an input device, just like the mouse, about every GUI package including [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) can give you this information. You could also look at [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/) for the [mouse](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html?highlight=mouse#module-pygame.mouse) package.

Screenshot of wxPython Demo showing mouse coordinates, actually being operated with a Watcom tablet:

[image]